# How to create a petition like form based on custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, forms

I'm trying to make a "petition" like function for a WordPress theme but I'm out of ideas.

Basically, here's what I try to achieve:

1. Create a custom post type
2. Creating a form so people can submit their signatures
3. Display the content in pages/posts using shortcodes.

Eg. [myshortcode posttypeid="1"]
    [signatures posttypeid="1"]
    [totalsignatures]

My question is how should I approach step 2? I know I can achieve both step 1 & 2 by messing with the db but I wanted to make it easier (and I hope it's possible) by using a custom post type.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: You need to make posts from front end. There are couple of plugins that can create a post from front end. Search on WP.ORG for suitable plugin. Once such plugin is [User Submitted Posts](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/user-submitted-posts)

Comment: Hey, I know how to make a form so users can submit the post but the point is how should I make/implement the signatures.